# Magento 2 hardcoded attribute sets

Tags: magento2, attributes, attribute-set

Is there any reason why Attribute sets are hardcoded in magento 2 in interfaces?

Example in **Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface** has const **ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_CUSTOMER=1**

**Magento\Rma\Api\RmaAttributesManagementInterface** has it too as **ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID=9**

Because of that - when you have non standard attribute set Ids (i.e. after data migration from M1) - you cannot save any custom attributes as they belong somewhere else

Example:

Customer entity save in admin happens in
**\Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save**

and data from request is populated using data object helper

```
$this->dataObjectHelper->populateWithArray(
       $customer,
       $customerData,
       '\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface'
       );
```

and that helper is trying to load all custom attributes using

**Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\CustomerMetadata** method **getAllAttributesMetadata()**

```
public function getAllAttributesMetadata()
    {
        /** @var AbstractAttribute[] $attribute */
        $attributeCodes = $this->attributeMetadataDataProvider->getAllAttributeCodes(
            self::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER,
            self::ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_CUSTOMER
        );

        $attributesMetadata = [];

        foreach ($attributeCodes as $attributeCode) {
            try {
                $attributesMetadata[] = $this->getAttributeMetadata($attributeCode);
            } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                //If no such entity, skip
            }
        }

        return $attributesMetadata;
    }
```

As you can see if your attribute set Id is non default one, all custom attributes will not be included there, so no data will be populated.

**eav_entity_table** has column for **default_attribute_set_id** per entity and it is not hardcoded there

Answer (score 0):

Well I reckon the problem here is that **by default Magento (1 or 2) does not allow you to change the attribute set for the customer entity.**

One attribute set is shipped by default with the software and its id is 1.

So in every install **unless you have used a module or a corrupted/manually modified database** this ID will always be 1.

Thus, when the data migration tool runs it will not work as your original database is not valid.

The solution would be to either temporary rewrite those classes or manually make changes in your database at your own risks. Maybe try to fix your M1 database first before migration.

Comment: During migration from M1 > M2 attribute_set_ids change (Even on a clean install)  You'll end with some attribute sets like Migration_* and default Magento 2 attribute sets will remain as well